# Are piranha and barracuda fish kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, fish

Rabbi Presworsky's book describing the various kosher/non-kosher creatures seen [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0979736714) says that piranha and barracuda are kosher fish based on their scales.

Are there any earlier poskim who have confirmed piranha and/or barracuda are kosher fish?

Comment: It is unclear why you ask that, is there any specific problem with them that make them stand out of the rule of scales?

Comment: Why do you think they might not be kosher? They have fins and easily-removable scales. I don't see a problem with them.

Comment: I believe CrC published a thorough article listing every kosher fish around. See if you can locate it, and B"N, I'll see if I can.

Comment: You have to act fast or they'll eat you first.

Comment: Here ([Rationalist Judaism](http://www.rationalistjudaism.com/2018/08/i-cant-believe-its-not-treife.html)) is a mention that says piranha is OK. I'm sure he would give you his sources if you asked.

Answer (score 1):

Although there doesn't seem to be much written online about the kashrus of piranha, [Chabad](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/82675/jewish/Kosher-Fish-List.htm) and the [Vaad HaKashrus of Ottowa](https://ovhkosher.ca/keeping-kosher/kosher-fish) both say baraccuda are kosher. The ["Traveling Rabbi"](http://travelingrabbi.com/jewish-travel/keeping-kosher-in-the-amazon-rainforest/index.html) appears to say some piranha are kosher and others aren't.